# Using *ngFor and $event based checkbox

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to generate a lists of checkboxes using ngfor. Everything works fine but if I check the 1st checkbox on the bottom card row it seems to think I checked the 1st box of the 1st card row.

Here's a small gif that demonstrates the issue.
http://www.giphy.com/gifs/dQpr1jkRci0DaZoLMl

```
<div *ngFor="let task of taskdata" class="card" >

    <div *ngIf="task.task1" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" 
                (change)="getdataonID($event.target.checked)" [checked]="task.isDone1">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">{{task.task1}}</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your checkboxes have the same ID. And clicking on any of the labels is supposed to select **the** checkbox identified by  `customCheck1`. But there are many of them. So that can't work.

There might be other problems, but you didn't post all the relevant code.

Comment: This was it. Having check box id was the problem. After I erased that it fixed the issue thanks! Sorry about not posting the whole code I will do it next time :)

Comment: @RandikaPeiris you shouldn't remove the ID. That will make it impossible to click the label to check or uncheck the checkbox. Instead, you should use **unique** IDs.

Comment: Allright, I haven't heard of that but will do some research. Anyway although I removed the ID, I'm able to check and uncheck the box and my functions work as well but as you said clicking the label is not possible anymore

Answer (score 2):

use the  **`[(ngModel)]`** with the checked attribute

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" 
 (change)="getdataonID($event.target.checked)"  [(ngModel)]="task.isDone1">
```

Comment: I'm using [checked] to get the previous state of the checkbox as stored in the DB. If I use ngmodel will will it affect that?

Comment: Nope it wont affect

Answer (score 0):

Check this [exmaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8aypph), I hope it will work for you. Instead of the event I am calling the method and passing element data as param and performing calculations in the component.